# How to peer verificate AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do I generate a public key that can be placed on HTTP clients to prevent MITM attack? I am using curl to connect to an API Gateway endpoint and I need a way for AWS to verify the validity of the certificate that the client sends.

Answer (score 2):

API Gateway doesn't support TLS mutual authentication on the frontend, so what you are asking is not possible.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to check validity of the server certificate. Is that possible?